# Prove $y=0$ is the unique solution of an ODE

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following problem.
"Prove that the only solution defined in all $\mathbb{R}$ of the ode $y'=y^2+\sin^2(xy)$ is $y=0$.

I can see that $f(x,y)=y^2+\sin^2(xy)$ verifies the conditions of Picard-Lindelof theorem but the theorem is local I don't know how to prove what I am asked. I have thought also of trying to solve de ode but seems not easy. Any idea? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hint: consider a similar ODE, $y’ = y^2$.

Comment: I  noticed that you got answers for many of your questions, but never *accepted* an answer so far. If you are not aware of it: Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/196432) for more information.

Comment: Ok, Martin R. I wasn't aware of that. I'll take it into account!

Comment: Picard theorem gives uniqueness too.